# How do I catch an error thrown by JNI_CreateJavaVM?

Tags: java-native-interface

```
PtrCreateJavaVM ptrCreateJavaVM = 
    (PtrCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
JNIEnv* env = NULL;
try {
    int x = ptrCreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
}catch (int e)
{
    printf("%d", e);
    fflush(0);
}
```

In case of a missing attached debugger, this code just exists the whole program and prints this to the console:

> ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused ERROR:
>   JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports
>   initialized [../. ./../src/share/back/debugInit.c:741] FATAL ERROR in
>   native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_E
>   RROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

I'd like to continue and log the error. How do I do that?

Comment: It doesn't 'throw' errors. It returns error values.

Answer (score 4):

`JNI_CreateJavaVM` is a normal C function and therefore doesn't throw C++ exceptions, so your `try-catch` is useless. It communicates through status codes. If `x` is `JNI_OK`, then the call was successful. Otherwise the value inside `x` is the error code.

Comment: @Blub JNI [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) is available that you can use when you code, as well as error codes (jni.h) that you can use in your code.

Comment: But that's my point: The program exits immediately. It doesn't return an int and doesn't allow me to log anything or continue executing.

Comment: @Blub That's not a part of the JNI specification and therefore nonstandard behavior that should never happen. I doubt that **anybody** can help you with that because the issue is on the JVM's side, not on your side. Although you could try passing a pointer to a custom `abort`/`exit` function in the JVM args. Maybe it calls one of those. That would allow you to "catch" the error. But I really wouldn't recommend that. Those functions are defined as nonreturning, so you must expect that violating this **will** break stuff.

Comment: hm thank you, that is weird. I'll try what you suggest and dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The fatal error is probably from the call that uses `ptrCreateJavaVM`. For it to work, `hinstLib` has to be a valid handle for `jvm.dll` (or equivalent) and `GetProcAddress` has to succeed.

The documentation for [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error
>   information, call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also be aware that the Win32 API that deals with strings has "ANSI" and Unicode versions of functions and structures. In recent decades, it's generally easier to use Unicode everywhere you can. (Java and .NET do; VB did; Windows and the WWW generally do.) So, try:

```
GetProcAddressW(hinstLib, L"JNI_CreateJavaVM")
```

where the "W" and "L" mean "wide" characters, which in the Win32 API and MSVC mean the UTF-16LE encoding of Unicode.

BTW—You could call JNI_CreateJavaVM directly and link in jvm.lib.

---

UPDATE:

Okay, you say the cause is your `args` results in a FATAL ERROR. So, you'll have to say either that is a bug in the JVM or your `args` aren't what you want since you do want to avoid a FATAL ERROR. Have you tried "suspend=y"?

Comment: No, the error is from the fact that I'm passing a wrong jvm argument to it. (i.e: It's expecting a listening debugger, but there is none so it exits with this error).

Comment: I know how to make args that don't result in a fatal error, I'm just unsure why I can't catch this one error